# How do I filter Relay results based on values in fields on Connected Types?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

This question is more about a pattern I keep encountering than a specific instance of the problem.

Often I'll have a `Relay` container that executes a query like this:

```
getUserGroup(id: $id) {
    users {
      edges {
        node {
          widgets {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                widgetTags {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      tagName
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In other words: I want to render the data in a `WidgetList` component like so:

```
// WidgetList.js
User1:
  Widget1: 
    TagA
    TagB
   Widget2: 
    TagA
    TagC
User 2: 
   // ..etc etc
```

My goal is to filter the `Widget` results based on their `WidgetTags`

My problem is that, in order to filter, I think I need all of the `WidgetTag` information at the parent level. Because not every `Widget` has any `Tags`, I have to enter the query from the `User` side.

How should one handle a pattern like this with `Relay`?

The options I've tried so far are:

1. Centralize any data I want to filter-on using a `state` management app like `Mobx`.  Each `Widget` adds its own data to the `store` upon `render` and with each `update`, then the `store` is used to filter the array of `Widgets` in the `WidgetList render()` function.
2. I manually pluck the relevant data from the `query` results at the `WidgetList` level, then carry out the same filtration steps as in step 1.

Neither of these feel in accordance with `Relay` best practices, though, so I'm wondering if there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument to you `widgets` field.
For example, you could add an argument "withTags" that takes as input an array of tags and only returns widgets which have theses tags:

`widgets(withTags: ['Sports', 'Art'])`

How does that sound to you?